# Strict Standards: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method

Tags: php

I have script : 
`function setttpidedata($data) {return call_user_func(array('ServicesImplttpidedata','setttpidedata'),$data);}`

in PHP 5.2 i get strick warning "Strict Standards: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method ServicesImplttpidedata::deletettpidedatamktime() should not be called statically in ".
in php old version  my script is running well. Could you please help to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got to pass a valid object to call a non-static method on it.

```
$z = new ServicesImplttpidedata();
call_user_func(array($z,'setttpidedata'),$data);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: z in D:\webroot\sidd\cmslibs\ttpidedataServices\ttpidedataServices.php on line 14

Comment: Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in

Comment: Yea obviously you didn't instantiate your class as in line 1 of my code?

Comment: This is my completely script:

`include 'ttpidedataModel.php';
include 'ttpidedataImpl.php';

$z = new ServicesImplttpidedata();

function setttpidedata($data) {return call_user_func(array($z,'setttpidedata'),$data);}`

Comment: ttpidedataImpl.php : 

`class ServicesImplttpidedata {
   function setttpidedata($data) {
    $dat=unserialize($data);
    $strQuery="insert into dbedm.ttpidedata (c_mktime_pide,i_doc) values ('".$dat->getc_mktime_pide()."','".$dat->geti_doc()."')";
$hasil=pg_query($strQuery);
    return $hasil;
  }
}`

Comment: Yea you would have to pass $z into the function or instantiate it inside the function. See http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: `$z = new ServicesImplttpidedata(); function setttpidedata($data) {global $z;return call_user_func(array($z,'setttpidedata'),$data);}`

running well. Thanks

Comment: @IrwanSetiawan global is not the best way to solve it though. Would be nice if you could pass me the accepted answer using the 'check' symbol next to my answer.